# It's possible to use a string within a string?

Tags: string

```
String name = user.get("name");
String username = "Welcome,$name";
```

I want to use the String `name` in String `username`.

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: `String username = "Welcome,"+name;`

Comment: You are asking about string Interpolation, and that is language dependent.  If it is not supported, then you have to use concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're using PHP, so I'm going to assume that's correct.

You can do the following for a string within a string:

```
$greeting = "Welcome, " . $name . "!";
$greeting = 'Welcome, ', $name, '!';
$greeting = 'Welcome, ' . $name . '!';
$greeting = "Welcome, $name!";
$greeting = "Welcome, {$name}!";
```

Use all but the first way as often as you'd like. Using double quotes makes PHP think that interpretation is needed, which reduces performance (however marginally). Varieties 2, 3, 4, and 5 will all give you the same result, although commas are considered more performant than periods, according to [this link](http://www.phpbench.com/).